Understanding Recovery Forks in SQL Server: Meaning and Significance
I'm trying to understand the concept of recovery forks in SQL Server, particularly in relation to the sys.database_recovery_status view. The documentation mentions several columns related to recovery forks, such as:

recovery_fork_guid
first_recovery_fork_guid
fork_point_lsn

However, I'm struggling to find clear explanations of what these mean and their significance. My specific questions are:

What exactly is a recovery fork in SQL Server?
How do recovery forks relate to database recovery processes?
What scenarios typically lead to the creation of a recovery fork?

I've searched online, but there seem to be very few articles that introduce or explain this concept in depth. Any insights or explanations would be greatly appreciated, as well as pointers to any comprehensive resources on this topic.

Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-recovery-status-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-log-architecture-and-management-guide?view=sql-server-ver16 may help shed more light right from the horses mouth too.

From the information I have gathered, I understand those GUID are kind of the DNA of the database and no matter how far on the kin line the database is, it shares info to identify itself and the first ancestor.
Stuart Moore's article has some info related to recovery forks and backups:

You restore a SQL Server database and you start 2 new things:

A new Recovery Fork
A new LSN chain

All databases are running along a Recovery Fork (identified by a
RecoveryForkGUID), even a new one will have one. You perform a
restore, and SQL Server will generate a new Recovery Fork under the
covers. Much like Ghostbusters, SQL Server won’t let you cross streams
As covered elsewhere on
here,
SQL Server uses LSNs (Log Sequence Numbers) to track database actions,
and as backups are database actions they are also linked to LSNs.
You’ll be taking the database back to an LSN in the past, and
restarting the count from there. This is why SQL Server uses the
recovery fork. Even if you were lucky enough to have backups starting
on the same LSN (and it’s the sort of luck where I’d be asking you for
the lottery numbers) you still won’t be able to use the backup.

I did some tests that brought me some understanding on the subject. This lab might help you understand the use of recovery forks:
--CREATE THE NEW DATABASE

CREATE DATABASE LabRecoveryFork;
GO

SELECT d.name, dsr.*
FROM sys.database_recovery_status AS dsr
INNER JOIN sys.databases AS d ON dsr.database_id = d.database_id
WHERE d.name = 'LabRecoveryFork';
GO

It creates our database LabRecoveryFork and shows info about database_guid, family_guid and recovery_fork_guid. Notice that family_guid and recovery_fork_guid are the same, it means that's the original database, it's the first of that "bloodline".

The sys.database_recovery_status doc says something about database_guid:

RESTORE always generates a new GUID when you restore a database that
does not yet exist.

--RESTORING A DATABASE THAT ALREADY EXISTS--

BACKUP DATABASE LabRecoveryFork TO DISK = 'C:\Backup\LabRecoveryFork.bak';
GO

RESTORE DATABASE LabRecoveryFork FROM DISK = 'C:\Backup\LabRecoveryFork.bak'
WITH replace;
GO

SELECT d.name, dsr.*
FROM sys.database_recovery_status AS dsr
INNER JOIN sys.databases AS d ON dsr.database_id = d.database_id
WHERE d.name = 'LabRecoveryFork';
GO

You'll see that database_guid, family_guid are the same as before, but recovery_fork_guid is different, and now we have some new information: last_log_backup_lsn, first_recovery_fork_guid and fork_point_lsn.
--RESTORIG A NEW DATABASE

RESTORE DATABASE LabRecoveryFork_2 FROM DISK = 'C:\Backup\LabRecoveryFork.bak'
WITH 
MOVE 'LabRecoveryFork' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\LabRecoveryFork_2.mdf',
MOVE 'LabRecoveryFork_Log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\LabRecoveryFork_2.ldf';
GO

SELECT d.name, dsr.*
FROM sys.database_recovery_status AS dsr
INNER JOIN sys.databases AS d ON dsr.database_id = d.database_id
WHERE d.name LIKE 'LabRecoveryFork%';
GO

Now we have a different database_guid since the restored database didn't exist before (as the documentation stated), but the family_guid is still the same as it indicates from what database this one was originated. Also, last_log_backup_lsn, first_recovery_fork_guid and fork_point_lsn are the same as before, since this database was originated from the same backup. Again, we have a different recovery_fork_guid.
Finally, we create the third database from a backup of the second one, instead of the original backup:
--RESTORIG A THIRD DATABASE FROM THE BACKUP OF THE SECOND DATABASE IN LINE

BACKUP DATABASE LabRecoveryFork_2 TO DISK = 'C:\Backup\LabRecoveryFork_2.bak';
GO

RESTORE DATABASE LabRecoveryFork_3 FROM DISK = 'C:\Backup\LabRecoveryFork_2.bak'
WITH 
MOVE 'LabRecoveryFork' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\LabRecoveryFork_3.mdf',
MOVE 'LabRecoveryFork_Log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\LabRecoveryFork_3.ldf';
GO

SELECT d.name, dsr.*
FROM sys.database_recovery_status AS dsr
INNER JOIN sys.databases AS d ON dsr.database_id = d.database_id
WHERE d.name LIKE 'LabRecoveryFork%';
GO

In this last case every information has changed, except family_guid.
Here's the result I got from this final step:

With that information, you can issue a RESTORE HEADERONLY to find how a backup relates to the database:
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\Backup\LabRecoveryFork_2.bak';

You can compare info related to recovery_fork and LSN to verify with what fork that backup is related (and can be used) with.

Great answer, respect

This article goes some way to answer some of your questions - albeit indirectly:
https://stuart-moore.com/please-clean-down-your-sql-server-backup-history/
If you understand the Backup and Recovery model for SQL Server you will get some understanding of recovery forks - it's basically just a way for SQL Server to ensure that recovery method/order is maintained (for example: that the latest Transaction Log backup you are trying to restore is consistent for the point in time of the database that you are trying to recover). A recovery fork starts at the point of a full restore or creation of a database and a few other scenarios related to clustering (I believe when you do a full failover in a cluster SQL server will start a new recovery fork).
Apparently AI answers aren't allowed in DBA Stack Exchange - but I found the best answers for your questions on ChatGPT - so if you have access I suggest you go use that tool. I'm not an overly excitable fan of AI - but it can be valuable in summarizing knowledge such as your questions - I put your questions (as presented) into ChatGPT 4o and it gave better and more understandable answers than anywhere I could find directly on the web.
